# jQuery error with logaed element

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem with my jQuery, because the script click(function () works with normal added html frame and don't work with .load frame

The script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".videos .youtube-video a").click(function (){
        alert(' ');
});
});
</script>

<div class="videos">
   <div class="youtube-video"> <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xB974isJSzY"></a> 
   </div>
</div>
```

It works but when add the same html code with jquery .click(function () don't work for this html code(the first one still works)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#loadpage').load("storie2.php", {'group_no':track_load}, function() {track_load++;});
});
</script>
```

change of order does not work as well. I don't understand why this loaded code doesn't work, Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) here to attach click handler to your dynamically added anchor:

```
$('#loadpage').on('click', '.videos .youtube-video a', function() {
    // Your code here
});
```